# How to hide Google Maps v2 Android zoom controls on interval

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, show

I would like to hide the zoom controls on a timed interval. Is there something I can call in the API to set the controls to fade out like they did in v1? Currently I've written some code to hide the controls after a set interval but before I go any further with it I was curious if there was already a known and better way of going about this.

```
    mTimer = new Timer();
        mapFragment.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                mapFragment.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                hideCameraOnInterval(5000);

            }
        });
```

And this is the method hideControlsOnInterval

```
public void hideCameraOnInterval(long milliseconds){
     TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mapFragment.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

                    }
                });

            }
        };

        mTimer.schedule(tt, milliseconds);       
 }
```

If there is not a better solution than I will implement logic to restart the TimerTask if it is going to be scheduled again before the delay is reached. If anyone has either a better solution or a good way to restart the task please submit an answer.